# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django' when creating project with mkproject

Tags: python, django, virtualenvwrapper

I am trying to create a django project using virtualenvwrapper. I have installed `virtualenvwrapper` and `virtualenvwrapper.django` template. But whenever I try to create a django project using `mkproject` command I get the error mentioned in the title. Here is my terminal output:

```
$ mkproject -t django todolist
Using base prefix '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7'
New python executable in /Users/tanmay/.virtualenvs/todolist/bin/python3.7
Not overwriting existing python script /Users/tanmay/.virtualenvs/todolist/bin/python (you must use /Users/tanmay/.virtualenvs/todolist/bin/python3.7)
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
done.
virtualenvwrapper_cd:cd:6: no such file or directory: /Users/tanmay/django-code/todolist
Creating /Users/tanmay/django-code/todolist
Setting project for todolist to /Users/tanmay/django-code/todolist

Applying template  django
Requirement already satisfied: django in /Users/tanmay/.virtualenvs/todolist/lib/python3.7/site-packages (2.1.7)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in /Users/tanmay/.virtualenvs/todolist/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from django) (2018.9)
virtualenvwrapper.django Running "django-admin.py startproject todolist"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tanmay/.virtualenvs/todolist/bin/django-admin.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.core import management
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
(todolist) ➜  todolist python
Python 3.7.0 (default, Oct  2 2018, 09:18:58)
[Clang 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.2)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from django import get_version
>>> get_version()
'2.1.7'
```

Also the list of pip packages in that environment:

```
(todolist) ➜  todolist pip list
Package    Version
---------- -------
Django     2.1.7
pip        19.0.3
pytz       2018.9
setuptools 40.8.0
wheel      0.33.1
```

As you can see, Django is installed. Also, I get the same message when I try to manually create a django project under that environment:

```
(todolist) ➜  django-code django-admin startproject mysite
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tanmay/.virtualenvs/todolist/bin/django-admin", line 6, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `head -1 /Users/tanmay/.virtualenvs/todolist/bin/django-admin`?

Comment: @phd `#!/usr/local/bin/python3`

Comment: That's the problem — it must be `#!/Users/tanmay/.virtualenvs/todolist/bin/python`. The [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) points to the global `python` and the global `python` doesn't have `django` installed, hence the error. `django-admin` must be run with the `python` from the virtualenv.

Comment: You are correct. Global python doesn't have django. Now what should be done in order to make virtualenvwrapper to pick up the python path from current virtual environment and not from global python?

Comment: Run `django-admin` with the proper interpreter. You can do it manually: `/Users/tanmay/.virtualenvs/todolist/bin/python /Users/tanmay/.virtualenvs/todolist/bin/django-admin`. Or fix the shebang line — edit file `django-admin` and replace the first line with `#!/Users/tanmay/.virtualenvs/todolist/bin/python`. In theory this must be done automatically at `pip install` time; I don't why `pip` didn't fix it itself.